# How do I ignore ampersands in a SQL script running from SQL Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a SQL script that creates a package with a comment containing an ampersand (&). When I run the script from SQL Plus, I am prompted to enter a substitute value for the string starting with &. How do I disable this feature so that SQL Plus ignores the ampersand?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
set define off
```

Otherwise the ampersand needs to be at the end of a string,

```
'StackOverflow &' || ' you'
```

EDIT:  I was click-happy when saving...  This was referenced from a [blog](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2008/09/using-ampersands-without-variable_15.html).

Comment: You can also specify this in the glogin.sql site profile setup file or the login.sql user profile setup file

Comment: This is the simplest solution if you aren't interested in substitution variables.

Answer (score 33):

If you sometimes use substitution variables you might not want to turn define off.  In these cases you could convert the ampersand from its numeric equivalent as in `|| Chr(38) ||` or append it as a single character as in `|| '&' ||`.

Comment: The specific scenario is a package whose source includes an ampersand in a comment. I don't see how I would use concatenation or substitution for this.

Comment: JoshL, you are correct I just listed this for completeness.  It is related to your question even though it doesn't directly answer your specific question.

Answer (score 16):

I resolved with the code below:

```
set escape on
```

and put a \ beside & in the left  `'value_\&_intert'`

Att

Comment: This worked for me. I was using the command `comment on column tablename.columnname is 'war ' || chr(38) || ' peace'` but it was giving me the error `ORA-01780: string literal required`.

Comment: Good solution if you still need to use & variables in the scripts. +1

Answer (score 9):

You can set the special character, which is looked for upon execution of a script, to another value by means of using the `SET DEFINE <1_CHARACTER>`

By default, the DEFINE function itself is on, and it is set to **&**

It can be turned off - as mentioned already - but it can be avoided as well by means of setting it to a different value. Be very aware of what sign you set it to. In the below example, I've chose the # character, but that choice is just an example.

```
SQL> select '&var_ampersand #var_hash' from dual;
Enter value for var_ampersand: a value

'AVALUE#VAR_HASH'
-----------------
a value #var_hash

SQL> set define #
SQL> r
  1* select '&var_ampersand #var_hash' from dual
Enter value for var_hash: another value

'&VAR_AMPERSANDANOTHERVALUE'
----------------------------
&var_ampersand another value

SQL>
```

Comment: I've used this approach myself recently. I like it as it doesn't require me to alter the contents of my PL/SQL packages.

Answer (score 5):

set define off      <- This is the best solution I found

I also tried...

set define }

I was able to insert several records containing ampersand characters '&' but I cannot use the '}' character into the text
So I decided to use "set define off" and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this nice FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#How_does_one_disable_interactive_prompting_in_SQL.2APlus.3F) there are a couple solutions.

You might also be able to escape the ampersand with the backslash character `\` if you can modify the comment.

Comment: The backslash escape does not work in SQL*Plus or SQLDeveloper

Comment: @JimTough It does after activating it with `set escape on`

Answer (score 0):

I had a CASE statement with WHEN column = 'sometext & more text' THEN ....

I replaced it with
WHEN column = 'sometext ' || CHR(38) || ' more text' THEN ...

you could also use
WHEN column LIKE 'sometext _ more text' THEN ...

(_ is the wildcard for a single character)