# Oracle special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, special-characters

I have a query

```
select * from table where name in ('52 T&M', '60 T&M');
```

The "&" is causing the query to expect a parameter.  How do I qualify the "&" in the query to sting so that the query can find string with the "&" character in them?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus

Comment: @ALL....my bad....this is in an Oracle 10g procedure. Not in SQL Server....sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would normally use `set define off` as suggested by omg but it is also possible to do it like this:

```
select *
from table
where name in ('52 T'||Chr(38)||'M', '60 T'||Chr(38)||'M');
```

Answer (score 9):

The ampersand ("&") is a character interpreted by SQLPlus as a variable placeholder.  Use:

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

Comment: @OMG...whereabouts in the Procedure would that code go?  As I mention below, the query is in a CURSOR degined before the BEGIN in the procedure

Comment: @MikeTWebb: At the top of the script.  I wager this is an anonymous PLSQL block...

Comment: +1 I learned something new today! @MikeTWebb It would go as the first line of the script or there abouts. Whether the script is defining a procedure, package body or function via `CREATE OR REPLACE ....` or the script contains an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Comment: I knew about using ampersands to define prompts. I didn't know how to turn them off. I had been using string concatenation as a work around. (`'Foo&'||'Bar'` for `'Foo&Bar'`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use sqlplus, so 
execute before

set scan off

Comment: @Michael....the query string is located in the definition of a CURSOR.  I tried your suggestion, but suspect the CURSOR definition is messing it up