# how to insert regular expression in a column

Tags: regex, oracle, insert, expression, multiple-columns

I would like to know how I can insert regular expression in a table column in a **Oracle** table.

```
insert into rule_master(rule)
values('^[0-how #'ff#'9]+$') where rule_id='7'
```

...but I am getting error syntax near where is wrong. I tried this with and with out single quotes. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: You can't INSERT using a WHERE, because no row exists yet. (If it did, your INSERT would fail as a duplicate if you've properly set up your tables.) You UPDATE using WHERE, you INSERT to add a new row. Find a SQL tutorial.

Comment: insert into abc values( 'how'pn'#'='#'#'the B''''); i tried this, but got the error       Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma        update abc set rollno='''how'pm''#'='#the is 'b''' where rollno=101;
this update is also showing error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669711/oracle-special-characters)

Comment: Not sure why that’s been picked as a duplicate - this has nothing to do with substitution varibales.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the invalid syntax using `where`, you also [need to escape the single quotes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) in your string by doubling them up:

> A single quotation mark (') within the literal must be preceded by an escape character. To represent one single quotation mark within a literal, enter two single quotation marks.

so with a normal text literal:

```
insert into rule_master(rule) values('^[0-how #''ff#''9]+$')
                                               ^^   ^^
```

or you can use [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) syntax, if you can identify a *`quote_delimiter`* character that will never appear in the value (or at least not immediately before a single quote); e.g. if you know `@` will never appear you can use a pattern like:

```
values(q'@<your actual value>@')
```

i.e.:

```
insert into rule_master(rule) values(q'@^[0-how #'ff#'9]+$@')
                                     ^ ^                  ^
```

If the `where` part is supposed to be populating that column at the same time then the syntax would be more like:

```
insert into rule_master(rule_id, rule)
values(7, q'@^[0-how #'ff#'9]+$@')
```

and if a row with that ID already exists you should be using `update` rather than `insert`:

```
update rule_master
set rule = q'@^[0-how #'ff#'9]+$@'
where rule_id = 7
```

or perhaps `merge` if you aren't sure.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now and if possible share the concept of deliiter and escaping character

Comment: Aren't those explained in the documentation I linked to? In the first version, from "To represent one single quotation mark within a literal, enter two single quotation marks", and in the second it has various things to say about *`quote_delimiter`*...