# handle special characters in PL/SQL procedures.?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I'm using oracle 10g plsql procedures for inserting and listing, but if we have any special characters like `'` (single quote ) and `&` etc. query fails. How to handle special characters in plsql?

before:

```
    lquery := 'select count(id) into lCount
                        From
                            dual
                        where
                            name = '||iName||'
                         and Id= '||iId
```

after:

```
     select into lCount
                        From
                            dual
                        where
                            Id= iId
                         and name = iName;
```

after changing the query its working fine. Problem is if we keep variable like name value inside single quotes some times query wont execute for special characters like `' , "` etc after changing query its working fine.

Comment: Please edit your post to include an example of code which fails. Also include information on how you're invoking this code as that may have a bearing on the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate your queries like that. Use parameters instead `select ... where id = :1 and name = :2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First how to handle a quote `'` and an ampersand `&`:

```
SQL@xe> set define off
SQL@xe> select q'(foo's & bar's)' from dual;

Q'(FOO'S&BAR'
-------------
foo's & bar's

SQL@xe>
```

See also [How do I ignore ampersands in a SQL script running from SQL Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118210/272735) and [Text Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm) for details of alternative quoting mechanism `q''`.

Second don't create SQL statements as strings but instead use [PL/SQL Static SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm). Static SQL will handle the quoting automatically for you (and is also SQL injection safe). Like:

```
declare
  lCount number;
  iName varchar2(20) := q'(foo's & bar's)';
  iId number := 42;
begin
  select count(*) into lCount From dual where name = iName and Id= iId;
end;
```