# Error in plsql code

Tags: plsql, syntax-error

Pleas help me to resolve this error in plsql.

```
 sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = 'INACTIVE' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count;
```

below is the error:

```
  ERROR at line 57:
  ORA-06550: line 57, column 66:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INACTIVE" when expecting one of the following:
  * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
  <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
  like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
  The symbol "* was inserted before "INACTIVE" to continue.
  ORA-06550: line 79, column 4:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:
  ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod
  null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted
  ORA-06550: line 81, column 7:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
  end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static member constructor map
```

Comment: Does this really need to be done with an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?  The query isn't dynamic, so you should be able to implement this with a standard cursor and an `OPEN`, `FETCH`, `CLOSE` or a `SELECT INTO`

Comment: This is essentially the same issue than e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22810334/272735

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo.

Comment: Also same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172315/wrong-symbol-inside-replace-function-pl-sql-oracle/48172423

Answer (score 11):

The quotes around `INACTIVE` are splitting the string up and causing the syntax error...

```
sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = ''INACTIVE'' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count;
```

Of course, if the statement isn't actually dynamic you don't need the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and can instead go with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   s_count
FROM   V$SESSION
WHERE  STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
AND    LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
   l_status varchar2(30):= 'INACTIVE';
   s_count number:= 0;
sqlquery varchar2(32767) := null;
begin
sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = :a  AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count using l_status ;
dbms_output.put_line(s_count);
end;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: in sqlquery variable , you can see :a is used as binding variable. Later on those value is passed while  "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count using l_status ;" by using l_status. It is just similar like preparedStatment in java.

Comment: it is also safe comparing to traditional string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = ''INACTIVE'' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Execute immediate

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
   l_status varchar2(30):= '''INACTIVE''';
   s_count number:= 0;
sqlquery varchar2(32767) := null;
begin
sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = '||l_status||' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count;
dbms_output.put_line(s_count);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM V$SESSION 
WHERE STATUS = ''INACTIVE'' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0' 
INTO s_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the query as 
sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = '''INACTIVE''' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count;

Answer (score 0):

Bind variables like Chandra said!

One way I like to assign the SQL:

```
declare
  vSQL varchar2( 100 ) ;
begin
  vSQL := q'[select 'done' from dual ]' ;
  dbms_output.put_line( vSQL ) ;
end ;
```

so you'd do:

```
sqlquery := q'[SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = :status AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0]';
```

Answer (score 0):

use :

> sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = ''INACTIVE'' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';

not :

> sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = 'INACTIVE' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';

Answer (score 0):

use this code will work perfectly

```
set serveroutput on
    DECLARE
    sqlquery    varchar2(1000);
    INACTIVE    varchar2(100):='INACTIVE';
    s_count     number;
    begin
    sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = '''||INACTIVE||''' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(s_count);
    end;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
            set serveroutput on;
            DECLARE
                sqlquery VARCHAR2(4000);
                s_count number;
            begin
                sqlquery := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = '||chr(39)||'INACTIVE'||chr(39)||' AND LAST_CALL_ET > 0';
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlquery into s_count;
                dbms_output.put_line('s_count--'||s_count);
            end;
            /
```