# Wrong symbol inside replace function (PL/SQL, ORACLE)

Tags: sql, function, plsql, package, oracle12c

I have below procedure inside package:

```
PROCEDURE test1
IS
     InsertST varchar2(32000) : = 'INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2) 
                                   (select cola, 
                                   INITCAP(REPLACE(colX, '_', ''))
                                   from tableB))';
Begin
    execute immediate InsertST;
END
```

during compilation I got error:

> Error(1177,45): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "_" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || member submultiset

Something is wrong with `"_"` inside function: `INITCAP(REPLACE(colX, '_', ''))`

How to fix it? Maybe is other way?

Comment: The parentheses in your `INSERT` statement are unbalanced.  Do you see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quoted string starting `'INSERT` ends at `colX, '`. To quote a quote you need to either double up the quotes:

```
'INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2) 
 (select cola, 
 INITCAP(REPLACE(colX, ''_'', ''''))
 from tableB))'
```

or else use q-quoting syntax:

```
q'[INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2) 
 (select cola, 
 INITCAP(REPLACE(colX, '_', ''))
 from tableB))]';
```

Also, the assignment operator is `:=` not `: =`.

It looks like you want to generate a statement like this:

```
insert into tablea ( col1, col2 )
select cola, initcap(replace(colx, '_', ''))
from   tableb
```

which has a couple less brackets.

It doesn't look like it needs to be dynamic at all, but I'm assuming this is a simplified version of something that does.

Comment: thanks @William, compiled without error, double quoting resolve issue!...and yes, it's part of something bigger ;)

Comment: @4est - Doubling the single-quotes is OK, but do consider the q-quoting mechanism, which William has also demonstrated. It is a far superior solution to doubling the single-quotes. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617