# How to insert '&user' in oracle column?

Tags: database, oracle

One of my oracle database columns needs to have the value 'user.password&user.user_name'
When I execute the query, I see a popup, because the query has '&user' in it. How do I get around it?

Example query:

```
update Table A set value = 'user.password&user.user_name' where id = 1;
```

Comment: I did search but was unable to land at the page. Sorry for duplicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the query to insert the value

```
'user.password'||chr(38)||'user.user_name'
```

Example query:

```
update Table A set value = 'user.password'||chr(38)||'user.user_name' where id = 1;
```

Comment: `'user.password'||'&'||'user.user_name'` should work as well.

Comment: @evilive of course it'll work. I feel stupid now for having needlessly complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

You can find several decisions at [How do I ignore ampersands in a SQL script running from SQL Plus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus)

Btw, you can use just `update table set value = &value where id = 1` and type your value into popup.

Answer (score 0):

`chr(38)` should work independent of the platform.

However, if you are using **SQL*Plus**, then you could use the sqlplus command:

```
set define off
```

In SQL*Plus, ampersand is used for **substitution variable**. The above command will ignore it.

For example,

```
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF
SQL> SELECT 'user.password&user.user_name' FROM DUAL;

'USER.PASSWORD&USER.USER_NAM
----------------------------
user.password&user.user_name

SQL>
```

Well, of course,**chr(38)** will work too:

```
SQL> SELECT 'user.password'||chr(38)||'user.user_name' FROM dual;

'USER.PASSWORD'||CHR(38)||'U
----------------------------
user.password&user.user_name

SQL>
```