# Constraint definition not properly inserted by query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have the below query from Oracle query point of view is that I have created a constraint on table `BOA_INVOICE` as shown below

```
ALTER TABLE BOA_INVOICE 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_INVOICE_SOURCE_SYSTEM 
       CHECK (SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('PCE', 'PDS', 'WALLSTREET', 'SYSTEM X & ECOTRADE'));
```

Now this constraint is added successfully for table `BOA_INVOICE` but the problem is that when I see the constraint definition in Oracle developer it is shown as shown below

```
SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('PCE', 'PDS', 'WALLSTREET', 'SYSTEM X null')
```

Now when I carefully observe the last value was `SYSTEM X & ECOTRADE` but in the constraint definition in oracle developer I can see it was displayed as
`SYSTEM X null`.

Please advise how can i correct this to `SYSTEM X & ECOTRADE` in the constraint definition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not Oracle, per se - it's SQL*Plus. The `&` is used to tell SQL*Plus that you're naming a parameter, and its presence in the string is confusing SQL*Plus.

There are two workarounds. First you can use `SET DEFINE OFF` to tell SQL*Plus that you're not using named parameters, and it should just treat the & like any other character.

The other way to do it is to put the & as the last character in the string, then concatenate the remainder of the string to the first one, as in

```
ALTER TABLE BOA_INVOICE 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_INVOICE_SOURCE_SYSTEM 
       CHECK (SOURCE_SYSTEM IN ('PCE', 'PDS', 'WALLSTREET', 'SYSTEM X &' || ' ECOTRADE'));
```

Best of luck.