# How to get ampersand value inside an XMLTYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltype

I have the below query:

```
select XMLType('<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>') from dual;
```

When i execute the above query,it executes perfectly fine and i get the following output:

```
<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>
```

But when i execute the following(which is my requirement):

```
select XMLType('<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1&v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>') from dual;
```

I am being asked to enter the value for '&' in a popup screen.

I have tried the following two ways:

```
select XMLType('<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1&amp;v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>') from dual;


select XMLType('<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1''&''v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>') from dual;
```

But still unable to get the OUTPUT correctly which should be:

```
<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1&v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>
```

*How can i achieve this?*

Comment: You didn't say what client you're using, but these options should work for most of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus

Comment: I am using Toad For Oracle

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here - `&` is a special character in *both* Oracle SQL and XML, and it has to be escaped in both. cdb_dba gave some examples of how to escape it in SQL (`CHR(38)` or & at the end of a string), and mkuligowski gave examples of how to escape it in XML (`&amp;` or CDATA), but the two kinds of escaping need to be combined. Here's a couple of examples:

```
-- with CHR() + CDATA
select XMLType('<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val><![CDATA[v1'|| chr(38) || 'v2]]></val>
  </TPL>
</root>') from dual;

-- with ampersand at the end of a string + "amp" character reference 
select XMLType('<root>
  <TPL>
    <fld>f7</fld><val>v1&' || 'amp;v2</val>
  </TPL>
</root>') from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I don't typically work with XMLType data, so I will add that to my list of things to watch out for if I ever happen to find myself in that area. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `v1''&''v2` or `v1&amp;v2`, try using `v1'|| chr(38) || 'v2` or `'v1 &'||'v2'`

chr(38) is ASCII for the amperstand, and the second option is just a different method of concatenating. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry but both the ways are actually not working

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you are using SQLDeveloper when querying. Try run `SET DEFINE OFF;` and you won't be prompted for the value .

Moreover, when you creating `XMLType` object then you should escape illegal characters, so following will work:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
select XMLType('<root>
 <TPL>
  <fld>f7</fld><val>v1&amp;v2</val>
 </TPL>
 </root>') from dual;
```

On the other hand, you can always wrap illegal character in `CDATA`:

```
select XMLType('<root>
 <TPL>
  <fld>f7</fld><val><![CDATA[v1&v2]]></val>
 </TPL>
</root>') from dual;
```

Comment: I am using Toad For Oracle ,Not SQL Developer

Comment: Well, I am using Oracle Version 11.0.0.116 and SET DEFINE OFF is not working

Comment: SET DEFINE is a SQLPlus command and must be executed with the script engine (F5). F9 executes single statements only and does not handle SQLPlus.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.But none of the above solution is working